# How to fix spasming and buggy instantiation in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

I'm creating a basic pool game in Unity with C#, what im trying to do is that if the cue ball is moving, the stick will disappear, and once it becomes stationary again, it will reappear to where the cue ball is located. This is my code so far:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class stickDeplacement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool bIsOnTheMove = false;
    Vector3 lastPos;
    public GameObject Stick;

    void Start()
    {

    }


    void Update()
    {
        var stick = Instantiate(Stick, gameObject.transform.position, gameObject.transform.rotation);
        if (this.transform.position != lastPos)
        {
            Destroy(stick);
            Debug.Log("Is moving");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Is not moving");
        }

        lastPos = this.transform.position;

    }


}
```

But what happens is that the ball, along with the stick, will just spasm and be buggy right from the start (when I open and play the game). Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- This is extremely inefficient and dangerous!

  Why instantiate a stick **every frame** just to eventually already destroy it in that very same frame? And if the ball is stationary you want an additional stick to be spawned every frame?

  Instead of all the time instantiating and destroying it at all you should rather keep **one** stick and only (de)activate it.

  In your case you could do this in a single line

  ```
  bIsOnTheMove = transform.position == lastPos;
  stick.SetActive(!bIsOnTheMove);
  ```
- Also I doubt a lot you would like the stick to have the same **rotation** as a rolling ball! Of course this will behave awkward

  Most certainly you do **not** simply want to clone the ball's orientation. I would e.g. try to determine the closest point of the table edge to the current ball's position (iterate  through the wall colliders and use [`Collider.ClosestPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.ClosestPoint.html)) and let the stick face the direction from that edge point towars the ball position (+ maybe an offset in X so the stick is slightly inclined by default).
- And finally you anyway do not want to assign that rotation every frame, since you most probably later want your users to be able to rotate that stick. You only want to apply this **once** when the ball becomes stationary.

Something like e.g.

```
// The stick is not a prefab anymore but simply always exists in the scene!
[SerializeField] private Transform stick;
[SerializeField] private Vector3 eulerOffset;
[SerializeField] private Collider[] wallColliders;

public bool bIsOnTheMove;

private Vector3 lastPos;

private void Start()
{
    lastPos = transform.position;
}

private void Update()
{
    // is the ball currently moving?
    var isMoving = transform.position == lastPos;
    last Post = transform.position;

    // Did this state change since the last frame?
    if(bIsOnTheMove == isMoving) return;
    bIsOnTheMove = isMoving;

    // (de)activate the stick accordingly
    stick.gameObject.SetActive(!isMoving);
    
    // Do this ONCE when ball becomes stanionary    
    if(!isMoving)
    {
        var ballPosition = transform.position;

        // among the wall colliders find which one is closest to the ball
        Vector3 closestPoint;
        var smallestDistance = float.PositiveInifinity;
        foreach(var wall in wallColliders)
        {
            var edgePoint = wall.ClosestPoint(ballPosition);
            var distane = (edgePoint - ballPosition).sqrMagnitude;
            if(distance < smallestDistance)
            {
                closestPoint = point;
                smallestDistance = distance;
            }
        }

        // then make the stick look towards the ball from that edge
        var direction = ballPosition - closestPoint;
        var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
        // optional add the offset
        rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(eulerOffset);
 
        stick.rotation = rotation;    
    }
}
```

Comment: Figures, actually this method of destroying and instantiating was actually done and what the my university professor demonstrated, I honestly thought its very inefficient. Thank you for this, I might have to defend myself in my demonstration for not using his method as he is very particular about it but im going to use and/or base my defense on this. Kudos to you kind sir